# Get content of textarea

Tags: python, html

I'm parsing HTML pages, on each one there is

`<textarea name="content[country]">...</textarea>`

Just need to get content of this textarea.

There's no lxml or other html parsing modules in my python version, because it's working inside a text-editor environment.

How do I parse text between opening and closing tags of the textarea with name `content[country]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you still have access to the stdlib, then you can use something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '<html><textarea name="content[country]">foo</textarea><textarea name="content[country]">bar</textarea></html>'
tree = ET.fromstring(s)
print [n.text for n in tree.iterfind('.//textarea[@name="content[country]"]')]
# ['foo', 'bar']
```

Horrible re hack:

```
import re
print re.findall(r'<\s*textarea.*?>(.*?)<', s)
```

Comment: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: Can it be parsed as string with regexp?

Comment: `<\s*textarea.*?>(.*?)<` this code stops on the first <tag> inside texarea

Comment: also won't work, if there is </textarea> in the content of parsed textarea

Comment: seems we have to escape characters first, then parse

Comment: @Steve I made no claims it would work - without being able to use a proper parser, or being able to see any sample data (which sounds like it's wonderfully mal-formed anyway)... I pass ;)